# Give an explicit injection from the permutations in Sn with an odd number of fixed points into the permutations with an even number of fixed points.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-geometry

I'm not sure where to start. I know to prove injectivity I have to show that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. 
So I would say there are two permutations of the same odd number with k fixed points. Where do I go from there?

Comment: Does the problem have an  assumption like $n \ge 3$? I ask since in $S_2$ the set of permutations with an odd number of fixed points is empty, and there can't be an injection of any kind whose domain is empty (without some revision of the term "injection").

Comment: Yes it is assumed $n\geq3$

Comment: @coffeemath Still as you increase the number of fixed points you decrease the number of possible permutations.

Comment: @coffeemath every map with empty domain is injective vacuously.

Comment: If $n=3$ there are four odd-fixed point permutations and two even-fixed point ones, so no injection. So you need to assume $n \ge 4.$

Answer (score -1):

Send the nth odd-number-of-fixed-points permutation to the nth even-number-of-fixed-points permutation under the dictionary order on the tuple-representation.

Comment: This really only depends on there being no more odd-number-of-fixed-points permutations than there are even-number-of-fixed-point-permutations. It may be OP is looking for more than such a generic injection, based in some way on the structures of the given permutations.